# npm config list - multiple config

Tags: npm

i have created a project using npm init and i created a .npmrc file with some config. when i check the npm config list i am getting project config and userconfig.

do i need to remove the userconfig , but i am not able to edit the file.

i am not understanding why we need the .npmrc file , when you hit a command npm install express , all the config is done in the npm config file ?

how to edit the .npmrc global file in ubuntu ?

do we need to remove the userconfig if we need to use project config ? or its something like which ever comes it takes that

Answer (score 0):

By Searching , i found some infos

when you install npm you have a global config file, whenever you need to access the global config file you can just add -g command

example : npm config list -g

for every projects you can  create a .npmrc file, in that file you can configure and you will have private kind of stuff like the packages which are hosted private

so for that you need to create a .npmrc file , if you check npm config list you will have both configs (.npmrc in project folder) and (.npmrc in global)

so its like first it will check with the config in the project folder, if there is no config for project folder it will check for the global config(userconfig)

no need to remove the global config , it will take first comes first serve so the project folder config will be taken if its there otherwise only it will check for the global config

**Editing the Global config file**

you can edit the global config file by going to

```
cd /

cd home/"username"/

vi .npmrc
```

change the file save it by using press esc  type :x